# What is the difference between classVariableNames: '' and instanceVariableNames: '' when setting up a Singleton in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

One is located on the instance side:

```
Object subclass: #MyClass
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    category: 'MyApp'
```

The other accessible on the class side:

```
MyClass class
    instanceVariableNames: ''
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable types in smalltalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967183/variable-types-in-smalltalk)

Comment: I was looking for an explanation on how the old syntax corresponds to the new. Can you look at my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes, I found bits of information here and there.

Managed to find a good explanation here, pasted in a few lines for reference purposes. People should read the entire column.
http://esug.org/data/Articles/Columns/EwingPapers/cvars&cinst_vars.pdf

> Classes that use class variables can be made more reusable with a few
>   coding conventions. These coding conventions make it easier to create
>   subclasses. Sometimes developers use class variables inappropriately.
>   Inappropriate use of class variables results in classes that are
>   difficult to subclass. Often, the better implementation choice for a
>   particular problem is a class instance variable instead of a class
>   variable.
>
> What are class variables? Classes can have
>
> • class
>   variables, and
>
> • class instances variables.
>
> Class variables are
>   referenced from instance and class methods by referring to the name of
>   the class variable. Any method, either a class method or an instance
>   method can reference a class variable.

Comment: PoolDictionaries and class instance variables are different concepts. A PoolDictionary is a global dictionary whose associations `name -> value` bind `name` to `value` in the scope of any class that uses the pool. A class instance variable is just an instance variable at the metaclass level.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new class (For example a Pen) you create a Class that is an instance of metaclass (this will be Pen class) and you will be able to get Pen instances that are instance of Pen class.

You can have a lot of Pen but you will have only one Pen class.

An instance variable is a variable of one instance. Each instance has it's own variable. Each Pen can have it's own color.

A class variable is a variable of a Class object (Pen class). As you have only one instance of Pen class, this variable will have only one value. If your pen has a class variable #DefaultColor, `myPenInstance class defaultColor` will return the same for all the Pen instances.

And last, an instance variable of the class side works as an instance variable of the instance side but for a class.

The difference between a class variable and an instance variable in the class side is that the class variable is unique for the class and it's subclasses while an instance variable in the class side will be specific for each of it's subclasses.

If you have a UniqueInstance class variable that stores a Singleton with an accessor in you Pen, `Pen uniqueInstance` and `PenSubclass uniqueInstance` will return the unique pen instance.

If you do the same with an instance variable in the class side, `Pen uniqueInstance` will return the Pen unique instance and `PenSubclass uniqueInstance` will return the PenSubclass unique instance.

Comment: What would be the right idiom for the singleton class: class variable (I've seen those to be used for this) or class side instance variables?

Comment: I try to use Singleton the less possible and I don't see cases where we need a hierarchy of Singleton's classes. So I use it in a class variable.